# How can i renew a Host Key in Azure function App without losing the link to the Key Vault?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have a Function App Hosted in Azure. I access the functions via a Key in the Host Keys that i created , MyKey. This is linked to a secret in the KeyVault via the following format :

```
     @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=secret_uri_with_version)
```

Now if the Key inside the function App is renewed, I lose the edited value as above and it is replaced with a random key value .
How can i make it so that if someone renews the key in the function app then the link to the Key Vault is not lost ?

Comment: are you not using a service principal to access azure KV from the function app ?

Comment: I have published a function using the example , https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio. But i set Access Rights to Function, so when i try to test the function i use a new testkey i created in Host Keys. If i renew the key then i have to go to Azure and use the new Key. I am trying to make it so that if the Key is renewed then i dont need to always go and get the key to run the function successfully. I want to be able to use a Key in the Vault regardless of renewal  will run the function. Or am i approaching the wrong way ?